# Setting collection name dynamically based on original directory structure

Tags: marklogic

I would like to dyamically add original directory name as
collection when loading files.

Suppose having following file: /home/sampledata/dir1/targetfile.xml
I would like targetfile.xml included in following collections:
"home", "sampledata", "dir1"

Can we do this while importing via MLCP?
or will be appreciate if anyone can share alternative way to achieve by script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
  let $dir-seprator := "/"
  for $uri in cts:uri-match("*")[fn:ends-with(.,'.xml')][1 to 10]
  let $collection := fn:substring-before($uri,fn:tokenize($uri,$dir-seprator)[fn:last()])
  return 
  xdmp:document-set-collections($uri,fn:tokenize($collection,$dir-seprator)[.!='']))
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't scale well. Good for small scale (50k docs max) ad hoc adjustments, but less useful in production..

Comment: If someone has bigger data size, can enhance this code to run this in batches.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an MLCP transform. It is most often used to manipulate the content before insert, but you can also adjust uri, collections, and more with it.

For generic details on MLCP transform, see: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518

For more specific details on transform output options, see: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_59764

HTH!